# How to get Pipeline Folder Path in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-deployment

Is there a way/function to fetch complete folder path of a pipeline in Azure data factory?

If I have a data factory job like in `str`:

```
**datafactory-name/root-folder/etl-pipeline**
```

I can use **@pipeline().Pipeline** function to fetch and store pipeline name in a variable which in this case would be **etl-pipeline**.

Is there a similar function to retrieve the name of folder in which the pipeline is? I would like to store **root-folder** also in a variable

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that there is any direct way to achieve this, however curious to know the use case why you would need to capture the name of the pipeline folder in a variable while executing it and why not parameterize the pipeline which would let you pass the name of the pipeline folder whenever you invoke the pipeline - this way you could still achieve what you are intending to do with pipeline parameter instead of a runtime initialized variable.

Comment: Why I am looking to do this is - say I have **folder-name/pipeline-name** in ADF. I am keeping the same structure in databricks as **folder-name/notebook-name**.

What I am looking to do is only expose 1 notebook as gateway to ADF and pass folder-name and pipeline-name from ADF and internally this gateway notebook will call specific notebooks based on these parameter values.

Comment: Got it, however currently there is no way to do get the pipeline full path using system variables and hence either you would have to manage it with pipeline parameters or submit your idea / suggestion here https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory?query=folder

Comment: Any more questions? Does it solve your problem? If yes, please accept it. If no, give the response